# Кеширование данных из MySQL в php скрипте

Tags: php, mysql

Такая задача: хранить имя сайта (+некоторые другие данные) в базе данных, что бы можно было легко менять. Раньше все хранил в конфиге сайта простой переменной. Но тут решил занести это в базу что бы легко было из админки менять.
Но так как запрос о имени сайта будет каждый раз запрашиваться из базы, подумал, не медленее ли это чем из файла и будет ли это нагружать дополнительно базу. Возможно нужно реализовать кеш? Что посоветуете?

Comment: Не надо мудрить. Сразу из базы в проект.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще всего сделать кеш методом записи выборки в массив, а потом:

```
file_put_contents ('./my_cache', serialize($config_array));
```

А читать:

```
$array = unserialize(@file_get_contents ('./my_cache'));
```

То что это будет насиловать сервер меньше, чем выборка из БД - 100%.

Если всё-таки не нужно править это через админку, то конечно лучше сделать .php-файл, где это всё записать в виде кода и иклудить его. Если же нужно править в админке - то как-то так, потому что я ярый противник писания( и последующего запуска) чистого РНР-кода из админки - это не безопасно и чревато перебоями в работе.

P.S. Если посещаемость сайта менее 100 человек в день - подобные заморочки нужны только для собственного развития.

Comment: >То что это будет насиловать сервер меньше, чем выборка из БД - 100%.
есть реальные примеры или это только предположение?

Comment: Запрос к БД:

- подключение к базе по сети или ФС-сокетом;

- открытие файла, подгрузка заголовков в память (если давно не было запросов);

- распаковка запроса, загрузка индексов в память;

- нахождение данных, подгрузка страницы данных;

- оформление и выдача результатов;

Почти все сопровождается обращениями к диску или его кешам.

В то время как файл это одно обращение к диску.

БД нужны для сложных выборок данных (за счет индексации и оптимизированных алгоритмов), простые вещи всегда быстрее работают на плоских файлах.

Comment: Делая один запрос - это да, файловая система будет быстрее. Делая 100 запросов, файловая система уже будет уступать по скорости БД. Хотя вещи-то простые затрагиваются. Засекая время после подключения к БД - скорости одинаковые при выборке 1 записи. А бд так или иначе будет подключаться. @Илюшка Овчинников я бы крайне не советовал кешировать простые запросы. Наоборот - кешировать нужно сложные.